# Manual computation of principal components disagrees with the fit_transform() output in Python

Tags: machine-learning, pca, python, scikit-learn

I am trying to do PCA from `sklearn` with `n_components = 5`. I apply the dimensionality reduction on my data using fit_transform(data) as defined here: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.PCA.html.

Initially I tried to do the classical matrix multiplication between `pca.components_` values and my `x_features` data, but the results are different. So I am whether doing my multiplication incorrectly or I did not understand how `fit_transform` work.

Below is a mock-up example to compare classic matrix multiplication and `fit_transform`:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn import decomposition
np.random.seed(0)
my_matrix = np.random.randn(100, 5)

mdl = decomposition.PCA(n_components=5)
mdl_FitTrans = mdl.fit_transform(my_matrix)
pca_components = mdl.components_
mdl_FitTrans_manual = np.dot(pca_components, my_matrix.transpose())
mdl_FitTrans_manualT = mdl_FitTrans_manual.transpose()
```

I am expecting `mdl_FitTrans == mdl_FitTrans_manual` but the result is `False`.

Comment: You need to center `my_matrix` before multiplying it with PCA eigenvectors.

Comment: since I cannot edit comments. these are the extra operations needed. `my_matrix_centered = my_matrix - np.mean(my_matrix,axis=0)` , `mdl_FitTrans_manual =  np.dot(my_matrix_centered, pca_components.T)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added the  answer from the comments here. Data needed centering as suggested by @amoeba. According to the documentation also (https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/a5ab948/sklearn/decomposition/base.py#L101)

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn import decomposition
np.random.seed(0)
my_matrix = np.random.randn(100, 5)

mdl = decomposition.PCA(n_components=5)
mdl_FitTrans = mdl.fit_transform(my_matrix)
pca_components = mdl.components_
my_matrix_centered = my_matrix - np.mean(my_matrix,axis=0) 
mdl_FitTrans_manual = np.dot(my_matrix_centered, pca_components.T)

(mdl_FitTrans.all() ==  mdl_FitTrans_manual.all())
True
```

EDIT: because I am not consistent with my variable naming